Number of cycles in the graph of Z/pZ induced by $g \to g^2$
If you create a graph where the vertices are elements $g \in Z/pZ$ and there is an edge from a to b if $b = a^2$.
How many cycles does this graph have for each p? Is there some property of p that tells us how many cycles the graph has?
I tried to look at examples Z/17Z has only two cycles centered in 1 and 0, but Z/29Z has four cycles, one centered in 16 and another in 23.

Is it correct to assume that $p$ is prime? Also, what is meant by a cycle being "centered in" a value?

Yes, also, centered just means that's a part of the cycle. Sorry, I should have said "including"

Note that cycles (except the $0$ cycle) can only occur in the subgroup of squares in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^{\ast}$. Moreover, if an element $a$ is contained in a cycle, then $x\mapsto x^2$ should be an automorphism on the subgroup generated by $a$.

Note the edit to my answer (after it was accepted) because I originally did not consider the $1 \to 1$ cycle carefully enough.

I am not 100 per cent sure that this is a duplicate of this old thread, but it is close. As I happened to answer that older one, I won't vote either way. My dupehammer privilege would make my vote immediately binding, but the case is not clear cut.

I mean, even though the linked question is looking at the same graph of transitions, the focus is different.

My absolute favorite variant of this graph showed up here, where both Misha and I shined to some extent :-)

Let's define $G_n$ to the be the directed graph with vertices $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and edges $k \to 2k$.
Why is this graph relevant? Because whenever $p$ is prime, there is a primitive root mod $p$: an nonzero element $r \in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ such that the elements of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ are $0$ and $1, r, r^2, r^3, \dots, r^{p-2}$, with $r^{p-1}=1$. Excluding $0$ (which forms a cycle in the squaring graph) the rest of the squaring graph is isomorphic to $G_{p-1}$, so the question is: how many cycles does $G_{p-1}$ have?
Moving on to $G_n$: when $n$ is even, we can separate is vertices into odd vertices and even vertices. The odd vertices $1, 3, 5, \dots, n-1$ will have edges to distinct even vertices. The even vertices $0, 2, 4, \dots, n-2$ will only have edges to each other, and they form a copy of $G_{n/2}$. Therefore $G_n$ and $G_{n/2}$ have the same number of cycles. Repeating this for each factor of $2$, we reduce to the case that $n$ is odd.
When $n$ is odd, multiplication by $2$ invertible mod $n$; therefore every vertex in $G_n$ has indegree $1$ as well as outdegree $1$. It is a cycle or a disjoint union of cycles. One of these cycles is the $0 \to 0$ cycle, and we ignore it. Another one of those cycles has the form $$1 \to 2 \to 4 \to \dots \to 2^k \to 1$$ for some $k$. In fact, whatever $k$ happens to be, it is not just the length of the cycle containing $1$, but the length of every cycle except $0 \to 0$, because each nonzero $a \in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is contained in the cycle $$a \to 2a \to 4a \to \dots \to 2^ka \to a.$$ Therefore there are $1 + (n-1)/k$ cycles of length $k$. What is $k$, in this case (where $n$ is odd)? It is exactly the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $n$. Note that $G_1$ just has one cycle.
Working backwards: when $n$ is even, let $2^t$ be the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$. Then $G_n$ has $1 + \frac{n/2^t - 1}{k}$ cycles, where $k$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $n/2^t$.
Finally, to answer the original question, let $2^t$ be the highest power of $2$ dividing $p-1$. Then the squaring graph has $2 + \frac{(p-1)/2^t - 1}{k}$ cycles, where $k$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $(p-1)/2^t$. (We add $1$ to include the cycle $0 \to 0$ where this is the $0$ in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.)
For example, when $p=17$, we can write $p-1=16$ as $2^4 \cdot 1$, and $G_1$ just has one cycle, so the squaring graph has two cycles.
When $p=29$, we can write $p-1=28$ as $2^2 \cdot 7$, and $G_7$ has three cycles ($0\to 0$, $1 \to 2 \to 4 \to 1$, and $3 \to 6 \to 5 \to 3$), because the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $7$ is $3$. so the squaring graph has four cycles. The formula is $2 + \frac{(29-1)/4-1}{3}$.
